# Is there a "request" like package using http2?

Tags: node.js, http, request, http2

We are using [request](https://github.com/request/request) at work. We now have access to `http2` for our server to server requests.

Do you know any node package with the same api (ish) as request that uses http2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and couldn't find a module.  This **isn't** a good solution but you can hack the *request* module to add http2.  As no one has chipped in with a better answer it's worth a mention.

This is what I did:

Add http2 as a boolean to the options object passed into *request*.

In node_modules/request run:

```
npm install http2
```

Open node_modules/request/request.js

Require the http2 module somewhere near the top:

```
, http2 = require('http2')
```

Make sure *request* doesn't add the "host" header (deprecated in HTTP2 and causes an error if the other end is using the http2 node module) so change line 304 (or so) to:

```
if (!self.hasHeader('host') && !options.http2) {
```

Add the http2 module to an object declaration on line 468 (or so) so it becomes:

```
, defaultModules = {'http:':http, 'https:':https, 'http2': http2}
```

Then make *request* use the new module after the variable declaration on the previous line.  Add this to line 471 (or so):

```
  if (options.http2) {
    protocol = 'http2';
  }
```

The rest of the application can remain unchanged, if options.http2 is not set then *request* behaves like it always does.

In a very unscientific test I found that making this change increased throughput to one service by about 25%.