# How to streaming data with POST request HTTP/2 AWS API in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http2, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-transcribe

I'm creating a NodeJs script to transcribe my recording file in real-time with Amazon Transcribe Service.
They have AWS SDK for javascript (aws-sdk-js) [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TranscribeService.html)

But this js SDK hasn't yet implement start streaming transcription. However, they have a API called /start-transcription with HTTP/2 definition [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_streaming_StartStreamTranscription.html)

So How can I request this AWS HTTP/2 API in NodeJS?

Comment: did you tried npm request?

Comment: @Ilan. Not yet. Does it support HTTP/2 request?

Comment: as I can see you can modify this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653110/is-there-a-request-like-package-using-http2, in addition you can take a look here https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-can-http-2-push-b491894e1bb1

Comment: @Ilan. I will try, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, did you manage to get this working? Any tips or tutorials would be good for aws fellow developers :D